# How to close the navigation drawer when an Item of ListView is selected?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I know that this question is asked many times but we have different situation. Regarding the project I downloaded the project navigation drawer demo from GitHub.com. Provided the code below:
this is the main activity:

```
package edu.ejapp.dotalegitstore;



@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
FragmentStackManager fm,sliding_menu;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    setUpView();
    menuToggeleSetUp(savedInstanceState);
}

void setUpView(){
    fm              = new FragmentStackManager(this);
    sliding_menu    = new FragmentStackManager(this);
    drawer     = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    fm.addFragment(new MainFragment(), R.id.main_frame, false, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE, false);
    sliding_menu.addFragment(new SlidingMenuFragment(), R.id.slide_fragment, false, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE, false);
}

void menuToggeleSetUp(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name
    ) {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item

    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle("COnfirm exit");
        dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
    else if (id == R.id.action_login) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
    else {

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

The base activity extended by MainActivity:

```
package edu.ejapp.dotalegitstore;

import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
public DrawerLayout drawer;

CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
CharSequence mTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setActionBar();
}
public void setActionBar(){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.app_main)));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

}

and lastly the sliding fragment activity, here the on item click is implemented not in baseactivity or main which is the reason of my problem: i cant close the drawer when i clicked item on the drawer:

```
public class SlidingMenuFragment extends Fragment {
List<String> data;
ListView list_view;
SlidingMenuListAdapter adapter;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sliding_menu, null);
    setUpView(root);
    return root;
}
void setUpView(ViewGroup root){
    list_view  =  (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    initList();
    setUpClick();
}
void initList(){
    data = new ArrayList<String>();

    data.add("Home");
    data.add("Arcana");
    data.add("Courrier");
    data.add("Hero Sets");
    data.add("Immortals");

    adapter = new SlidingMenuListAdapter(getActivity(),data);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

}
void setUpClick(){
    list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hi "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
}
}
```

I didnt include the other files such as the xmls. My question is:

1. How can I close the drawer when I clicked item of the list view provided that the onitemclick is defined in SlidingMenuFragment class and the mDrawerlayout is located in BaseActivity class which is extended by MainActivity class?

Comment: The activity that the drawer is attached to... THAT activity you either need to get access to so as to call close or pass the activity so that it can be used during the click. Maybe a static method or just passing this, maybe a handler. I assume getActivity() from the frag gets the wrong activity (or did you not try that)? It looks like might benefit with a more refined question... The title is a bit misleading even though that's the end of what's needed (its not really what you need).

Comment: Ahh okay sir.. Im sorry. But thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

create a method to close drawer in your main activity and call it from fragment.

```
public static void closeDrawer(){
    if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(leftDrawerList)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(leftDrawerList);
    }
}
```

Inside Fragment

```
 MainActivity.closeDrawer();
```

Comment: Thnak you for your response sir!

Comment: i cant vote up sir because my reputation is not 15 so sorry

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion：
provide an interface in SlidingMenuFragment like:

```
public class SlidingMenuFragment extends Fragment {
            private OnListItemClickListener mOnListItemClickListener;
            //here is mOnListItemClickListener getter and setter method
            public *** set(get)OnListItemClickListener(){};
            //define a interface here
            public interface OnListItemClickListener{
                public void onListenItemClick();
            }
            .
            .
            .
        void setUpClick(){
            list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                           if(mOnListItemClickListener != null){
                               mOnListItemClickListener.onListenItemClick();
                           }

                    }
                });
        }
        }
```

and then you should implement this interface in your MainActivity class like:

```
  public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    void setUpView(){
        fm              = new FragmentStackManager(this);
        sliding_menu    = new FragmentStackManager(this);
        drawer     = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        fm.addFragment(new MainFragment(), R.id.main_frame, false, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE, false);
     SlidingMenuFragment smFragment = new SlidingMenuFragment()
    smFragment.setMonListItemClickListener(new OnListItemClickListener(){
    public void onListenItemClick(){
    drawer.close();
    }
    });
    sliding_menu.addFragment(smFragment, R.id.slide_fragment, false, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE, false);
}
}`
```

Comment: Sir what is the MainFragment()? Im really really sorry Im new to android.

Comment: the code i put up was the code u give out in the question, i just reference them to show you the method to solve your problem,you can find the MainFragment in your project.